# Move some files to another path in windows phone with c# and unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-phone, storage, windows-10-mobile

I saved some images to application persistence data path in windows phone with unity3d and c#. How can I move this images to Picture folder in my phone or exist another way to save directly to Pictures?

Comment: Have you tried any code or still trying to achieve this with telepathy?

Comment: Yes I try any code, I try to move File.Move(...). What did you mean by telepathy ?